# difference between Reformat Code / Reformat Code with dartfmt

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, code-formatting

In Android studio,  when I open a dart file, I see two options to format the code, so my question is

What is the difference between Reformat Code / Reformat Code with dartfmt

[image]

Comment: I always use `ctrl + alt + L`. But if you havent added comma(`,`) correctly in your widget tree. It will act weird.

Answer (score 4):

Difference between them I don't know but I know how you can add a shortcut to format code:
Go to

```
File -> Settings -> Keymap -> Editor Action -> Reformate Code with dartfmt
```

and add click on it and add a shortcut

Answer (score 2):

Both are the same essentially.

The only difference is that `Reformat Code (ctrl + alt + L)` applies only to the file open in the Editor or the file selected in project files pane using `Intellij`'s Code formatter feature.

While `Reformat Code using dartfmt` uses `dartfmt` CLI command available with the `flutter` SDK.

The output of both will be the same. `dartfmt` allow you to format the code on directory level and from a cmd/terminal instead of an IDE.

Answer (score 0):

**Automatically formatting code in Android Studio and IntelliJ
**
Install the Dart plugin to get automatic formatting of code in Android Studio and IntelliJ.

To automatically format the code in the current source code window, right-click in the code window and select Reformat Code with dartfmt. You can add a keyboard shortcut to this in Keymap section of IntelliJ Preferences.

You can also do it with

flutter format path1 path2 ...
(From terminal window)

[Official link to flutter formatting tool](https://dart.dev/tools/dartfmt)
This shows that dartfmt is just a formatter by dart specifically for dart files. Default format code given by Android studio also could do this if file extension is identified by Android studio.

Comment: is there output same/identical?

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question.